# how to get sequence in the query for a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have few records as follows:

```
column_1      column_2       column_3   column_4
abc            xyz            sra         123
abc            xyz            sra         234
def            gth            har         678
def            gts            har         965
def            gts            har         376
xyz            wxyz            sra         567
xyz            wxyz            sra         734
abc            xyz            har         26
abc            xyz            har         24
```

I want a query to display as below, using pl sql analytical functions column 5 should produce sequence:

```
column_1      column_2       column_3   column_4  coulmn_5
abc            xyz            sra         123       1
abc            xyz            sra         234       1
abc            xyz            har         26        2
abc            xyz            har         24        2
def            gth            har         678       3
def            gts            har         965       3
def            gts            har         376       3
xyz           wxyz            sra         567       4
xyz           wxyz            sra         734       4
```

Comment: what have you tried? what does `column_5` come from? You need to be more specific

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure? You also need to explain what the logic behind the numbering in `column_5` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't explain what you want, so I have to guess.

```
select column_1, 
       column_2,
       column_3,
       column_4,
       dense_rank() over (order by column_1, column_3) as column_5
from the_table
order by column_1, column_4
```

This assumes that `abdc` and `abcd` in the sample data is a typo and should actually be two times `abcd`. If that is not a typo, then the window function might should probably be changed to use `order by column_3`

Comment: There are duplicates for the column_1 so this query doesn't work.select column_1, 
       column_2,
       column_3,
       column_4,
       dense_rank() over (order by column_1,column_2,column_3) as column_5
from the_table is working. Thanks for answer

Comment: Then add more columns to the `order by`, e.g `over (order by column_1, column_3) `

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,DENSE_RANK() WITHIN GROUP 
   (PARTITION BY column_1 ORDER BY column_1 ) "column_5"
```